# Mysql subquery very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this MySQL question. It works fine, but it's extremly slow. It takes up to 30 seconds to run.

```
SELECT t.Id, Subject, k.info
FROM tip t
LEFT JOIN comments k ON t.Id = k.Tipid
WHERE event = 1
AND k.Id
IN (
SELECT Max(Id) FROM comments GROUP BY Tipid
)
```

If I run only the subquery (`SELECT Max(Id) FROM comments GROUP BY Tipid`) it takes about 0.02 seconds to run.

Something is wrong with the subquery. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: When asking a question about query performance, try to include some detail about the tables you are using e.g. rows in table, indexes. Also try running your query with the word `EXPLAIN` at the beginning to generate an execution plan trace and post that up as it's very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need group by if you select max(id) try this

```
    SELECT t.Id, Subject, k.info
    FROM tip t
    LEFT JOIN comments k ON t.Id = k.Tipid
    WHERE event = 1
    AND k.Id in (select Max(Id) from comments)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Subject, c.info
FROM tip t
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT Tipid, MAX(Id) AS MaxId
   FROM comments 
   GROUP BY Tipid
) AS c  ON t.Id = c.Tipid
       AND t.Id = c.MaxId
WHERE t.event = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason for this...
i think u try this one...

```
SELECT t.Id, Subject, k.info
FROM tip t
INNER JOIN comments k ON t.Id = k.Tipid
WHERE event = 1
  AND k.Id IN ( SELECT Max(Id) FROM comments GROUP BY Tipid )
```

Because LEFT JOIN is become too slow after 50 records.